# Kitchen login failed :Could not resolve host name

Tags: docker, ssh, test-kitchen

I am using test-kitchen and created a centos docker image. my `.kitchen.yml` file looks like this 
[image]

I have performed `kitchen create`and `kitchen converge` command and then looked into the created files with `kitchen list`
[image]

and I also have a docker image created when I used the kitchen create
[image]
now that I have everything I want to run the image and I am using `kitchen login` command and I am receiving following error

[image]
Is this a correct procedure to login to a docker container? or am I doing anything wrong in the .kitchen.yml file?.
Note: I have looked into various issues but nothing helped me so finally, I am asking it here.

EDIT: I have resolved the above issue and facing this new one 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue it was a configuration problem. I've modified my docker file and everything up and working now